# Problem with JWT Token while Authenticating the user

Tags: c#, .net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I have web api which is authorized and i have implemented JWT refresh Token security and everything works fine. When I enter valid password and username it response me back accesstoken and refeshtoken.

So the problem is that when i request token i get it back and that token expires in 1 day but when i change user credentials like password and role and even if send request using old token i stay authenticated or system allows me to access the resources.

Here is my API

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<string> Foo()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }
```

Here is my startup class's Configure method

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var tokenKey = "This is my secret key of the token";
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(tokenKey);

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.SaveToken = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromDays(10)
                };
                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        if (context.Exception.GetType() == typeof(SecurityTokenExpiredException))
                        {
                            context.Response.Headers.Add("Token-Expired", "true");
                        }
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });

            services.AddControllersWithViews(option =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                                .RequireRole("Consumer", "Admin")
                                .Build();
                option.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            });
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "CodeFactoryAPI", Version = "v1" });
            });

            services.AddDbContextPool<AdminContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("CodeFactoryAPI")));
            services.AddSingleton<string>(tokenKey);
        }
```

Here is the code that generates JWT token

```
    public class AuthenticationService : IDisposable
    {
        private AdminContext context;
        private bool disposed = false;
        private readonly string tokenKey;

        public AuthenticationService(AdminContext context, string tokenKey)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.tokenKey = tokenKey;
        }

        public async Task<(string accessToken, string refeshToken)> Authenticate(string userName, string password)
        {
            var consumer = await context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.ConsumerName == userName &&
                                                                    u.Password == password);
            if (consumer is null)
                return default;

            consumer.Token = GenerateRefreshToken();
            consumer.IssuedToken = DateTime.Today;

            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(tokenKey);

            Claim[] claims = new Claim[] { new(ClaimTypes.Name, userName + ',' + password), new(ClaimTypes.Role, consumer.Role) };

            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
                SigningCredentials = new(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
            };
            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

            context.Update(consumer);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            return (tokenHandler.WriteToken(token), consumer.Token);
        }

        public async Task<(string accessToken, string refeshToken)> ReAuthenticate(string refreshToken)
        {
            var consumer = await context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Token == refreshToken)
                                              .ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (consumer is null || consumer.IssuedToken == null || (DateTime.Today - consumer.IssuedToken.Value).Days > 30)
                return default;

            consumer.Token = GenerateRefreshToken();
            consumer.IssuedToken = DateTime.Today;

            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(tokenKey);
            var claims = new Claim[] { new(ClaimTypes.Name, consumer.ConsumerName + ',' + consumer.Password) };

            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
                SigningCredentials = new(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
            };

            var tokens = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
            var acceessToken = tokenHandler.WriteToken(tokens);

            context.Update(consumer);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            return (acceessToken, consumer.Token);
        }

        public string GenerateRefreshToken()
        {
            var randomNumber = new byte[32];
            using var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
            rng.GetBytes(randomNumber);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(randomNumber);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
        }

        public void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    context.Dispose();
                }
                context = null;
                disposed = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

so when i update any users data and even if try to access resource i can.

here is screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0qla.png)

then if i update user data like username and password

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3jZy.png)

and i try to access resource using old token i stay authenticated

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1wRT.png)

What is causing the problem and how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `TokenValidationParameters.ValidateLifetime = true`?

Comment: @jegtugado I tried but it doesn't work

Comment: Also `ClockSkew` should be set to `TimeSpan.Zero` if you want the token to expire exactly at the expiration value. Hard to say why it works when you change password or role. Is it possible you don't have an initial role and your `ClockSkew` is allowing the old token that seems expired to work since you have set it to `TimeSpan.FromDays(10)`?

Comment: @jegtugado even if i set ClockSkew to TimeSpan.Zero it does not work and please can you explain what do you mean by "is it possible you don't have an initial role and your ClockSkew". .Thank you!

Comment: @SohamPatel This is not an error. JWTs are working like that by design. Unless you store every issued token server-side and validate any incoming token against the database, the token will be valid until its expiration date is reached. That's one difference between cookies and JWTs

Comment: @SohamPatel It will work unless and until it's expired and you can't explicitly expire it. The client who uses this token just destroys it from their end when they logout. If they won't they can access the resource.

Comment: Just got back, so I thought your problem was your app is *validating expired tokens* but it turns out you are worried about old tokens working after issuing a new one. JWT tokens are design to be validated based on the information on the token, nothing more. It's a design that considers performance. You can see many talks about this on youtube that should address your concerns. You can create a blacklist of old tokens if you want to invalidate them but that is counter intuitive as to why you used tokens in the first place. Also consider dropping role based auth and do claims based instead.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the comments, JWT Tokens are signed and that's the reason why they are trusted in contrast to storing them server-side. This is desirable for several reasons such as being stateless and being able to seperate the login/token handling (I call this auth service) etc from the actual resource service.

To be able to "revoke", Refresh Tokens are introduced:
Refresh Tokens are usually long random Nonces and are also saved server side on the auth service. When a user logins, the service will return the *short-lived* access-token *and* the refresh-token.

The user can now access resource services with the access-token as usual. If the access-token expires, it can use his refresh-token to get a new access-token from the auth-service without any user input.

Now to your password change scenario: In that case, you will delete/invalidate the refresh-token saved on the auth-service. Hence, when the current access-token is expired, the user cannot get a new one anymore.

In short: Short-lived access-tokens and long-lived refresh-tokens provide a revoke mechanism.

Comment: i agree with you bro but what if i have given to access token to user with expriration time of 1 day and after 1 hour i want to disable it's token for some reason then so what should i do?

Comment: You can reduce the lifetime of the access-token down to the time that you still find accaptable for revocation. Or if you *really really* need that functionality, you could also implement a blacklist of usernames that you would query while validating the JWT token.